# JSF wont let me put action in form tag

Tags: jsf

JSF do not let me to put action url in my form when using `<h:form>`. It is advised to use plain  html - `<form>` tag. But that won't save bean values in form in database. What is the use of that, obviously JSF creators know, I certianly  don't.

It's possible to set url with command button. But, my Command button has method names - so it can't point to urls. How to set it easy?

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve for which you  incorrectly thought that changing the JSF form's action would be the right solution?

Comment: Sorry for being late, I managed to bypass this!